# Error "503 OUT OF DISK SPACE" when installing a package

Tags: apt, repository

Possible answer
[Unable to play MP3 or MP4 files in Rhythmbox or Movie Player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332141/unable-to-play-mp3-mp4-in-rhythmbox-movie-player)

Rhythmbox is unable to found mpeg mp3 plugin though vlc is able to play mp3 files.

I tried to install ubutnu-restricted-extras but it gives the following error

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe libavcodec-extra-53 amd64 6:0.8.9ubuntu0.13.10.1
  503  OUT OF DISK SPACE
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/universe libavcodec-extra-53 amd64 6:0.8.9ubuntu0.13.10.1
  503  OUT OF DISK SPACE
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav-extra/libavcodec-extra-53_0.8.9ubuntu0.13.10.1_amd64.deb  503  OUT OF DISK SPACE
```

The problem persist.

EDIT:

To be clear my root has 450 GB space unused.

**df -**h gives:

```
/dev/sda1       455G  4.3G  428G   1% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           382M  1.2M  381M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  184K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Moreover I have found that the home folder(/home/aul) is full but I don't have a clue why.Please have a look at the screen shots and help if you can figure it out

Have a look at the link for the image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLdmce2ArlLanRYMHZURVNVdHM/edit?usp=sharing

Since I have space left what should be done to avoid this in future?

Do I have to create a new partition?
I have recently format it so I don't have any issue reformatting it.What should I keep in mind while reformating?

Comment: If I am correct VLC can play mp3 on its own because it comes wit its own codecs, Rhythmbox however needs the restricted extras

Comment: Since it looks like you have only one partition `/home/aul` can not be full, as it is located in the root partition. Your problem seems strange. Please post the exact command you used to install the packages.

Comment: For the answers saying the user is out of disk space, please notice that the error is `503 OUT OF DISK SPACE`. Which means the error comes from web-server at `archive.ubuntu.com`. @Atul Try running `sudo apt-get update` and the try installing the packages again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is from the server, so either it is broken ( unlikely ) or you are using a proxy server and *it* is broken/out of space.  Wait a while and it will probably clear up.

Comment: You are right, should have thought about that. Ill remove my answer.