# Make Rhythmbox play .mp4 files

Tags: rhythmbox, mp4

Once my Rhythmbox was capable of playing **.mp4** files, but I can't seem to make it the same again.

I tried installing:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get build-dep rhythmbox

sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install faad
sudo apt-get install libfaad2
sudo apt-get install libav-tools 
sudo apt-get install libavcodec57

sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-base
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-bad
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-ugly
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools
sudo apt-get install totem
```

But no success. My sources:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/m4a-and-m4p-playback-with-rhythmbox-523497/

[Unable to play MP3 or MP4 files in Rhythmbox or Movie Player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332141/unable-to-play-mp3-or-mp4-files-in-rhythmbox-or-movie-player)

Comment: if you uninstalled Totem, try to reinstall it `sudo apt install totem`

Comment: It wasn't installed, I just installed it but it did not make a difference.. (I updated the post).

Comment: Totem does play mp4 on my system, whereas Rhythmbox does not.

Comment: I used to be able to add .mp4 files to Rhythmbox playlists, I can't do it anymore (Clementine can do it now).

Comment: seeing as mp4 are meant for storing video not just audio, it would seem that this choice is by design

Comment: Poor design in my opinion, @tatsu. mp4 files obviously can contain audio tracks. Folks are not going to extract 1000s of audio tracks from their music videos just for the sake of being able to *also* play them in just one of their many players.